# React Updating Components after Updating 2D Grid in Redux Store?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm having an architectural dilemma. I am making a website to display pathfinding algorithms. I am using Redux to store a 2D array which represents the state of each cell in the grid.

The way my application works is that I have a classes that inherit from a base class called PathfindingAlgorithm which has a function called pass() that does one pass of the algorithm and updates the grid in the store.

Below is an example of Depth First Search being implemented. My 'SET_CELL_STATE' redux action updates the 2D grid in my redux store with the newState. Coordinate just holds {x, y} values, and coordinateMap is there for backtracking on the path.

```
export class DepthFirstSearch extends PathfindingAlgorithm {
    private stack: coordinate[] = [this.startIndex];
    private coordinateMap: Map<coordinate, coordinate> = new Map();
    private current: any;

    public pass(): boolean {
        const {grid} = store.getState();
        if (this.stack.length !== 0) {
            this.currentIndex = this.stack[this.stack.length - 1];
            this.stack.pop();

            if (grid[this.currentIndex.y][this.currentIndex.x] === CellState.Exit) {
                return true;
            } else if (grid[this.currentIndex.y][this.currentIndex.x] === CellState.Empty) {
                store.dispatch({
                    type: 'SET_CELL_STATE',
                    x: this.currentIndex.x,
                    y: this.currentIndex.y,
                   newState: CellState.Visited});
            }
            const neighbors = super.getUnvisitedNeighbors(this.currentIndex.x, this.currentIndex.y);

            neighbors.forEach(val => {
                this.coordinateMap.set(val, this.currentIndex);

                this.stack.push(val);
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

I want to call pass until I find an exit and have my view components update in response to the 2D grid. For the view, I dynamically generate cells based on the 2D grid.

```
function Board(props: any) {
    const grid = props.grid;

    const renderBoard = () => {
        return grid.map((gridRow: Array<CellState>, i: number) => {
            return gridRow.map((gridItem: CellState, j: number) => {
                return (
                    <div key={uuidv4()}>
                        <Cell x={j} y={i}/>
                    </div>);
            })
        });
    }

    return(
        <BoardView
            renderBoard = { renderBoard }
        />
    );
}

function BoardView(props: any) {
    const { renderBoard } = props;

    return(
        <div className="board">
            { renderBoard() }
        </div>
    );
}
```

How can I efficiently achieve this looping effect? Making a while loop inside the button that starts it does not update the components until the loop is finished which is bad since I want to animate this in the future. Should I just directly change the Cells straight from the DOM?